# Links not working inside div element that appears on mouse over

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a JavaScript function which will parse data (which will be retrieved from a database, but its just static here for testing) and format it into links and place it into a div element (popup) that will show up when the mouse is hovered onto the icon. However, I cannot figure out why the links are not clickable. I can right click it and open it in a new tab, but I cannot directly click and open them. Also, it works on Firefox, but not Chrome, or Safari!

EDITED:

Here is the code in JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kvdju2ju/2/

HTML

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div id="p1" class="parent">
          <img src="http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/blue-square-icon-47147.png" style="border-width:0px;"/>
          <div id="p1data" class="data" style="display:none">
             Website1#http://www.google.com#Website2#http://www.Link2.com#Website3#http://www.Link3.com"
          </div>
          <div id="p1popup" class="popup" style="display: none">
          </div>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.parent .popup {
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left:20px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: black solid 1px;
}

.parent:hover .popup {
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left:20px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 100;
  outline: black solid 1px;
}

.popup a:link { color: #003300; text-decoration: none;}
.popup a:visited { color: #003300; }
.popup a:hover { color: #006600; }
.popup a:active { color: #006600; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the nodes like this (It works on Chrome):

```
function parseWebsites() {
    var text = document.getElementById('p1data').innerHTML;
    var lines = text.split("#");
    var string = "";
    var myNode = document.getElementById("p1data");
    while (myNode.firstChild) {
        myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i = i + 2) {
       var webtitle = lines[i];
       var website = lines[i + 1];
       //string = string + "<a href='" + website + "' target='_blank'>" + webtitle + "</a> <br> ";
       var node = document.createElement("a"); // Create a <a> node
       var textnode = document.createTextNode(webtitle); // Create a text node
       node.appendChild(textnode); // Append the text to <a>
       node.href = website;
       node.target = "_blank";
       document.getElementById("p1popup").appendChild(node); // Append <a> to <div> with id="p1popup"
       var br = document.createElement("br"); // Create a <br> node
       document.getElementById("p1popup").appendChild(br);
   }
   //document.getElementById("p1popup").innerHTML = string;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s8st79w0/1/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an anchor  and you don't have href

you have missing href
try adding one

```
<a id="p1" class="parent" href='https://www.google.com'>
 <div> 


   <img src="http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/blue-square-icon-47147.png"   style="border-width:0px;" />

   <div id="p1data" class="data" style="display:none">
        website1#http://www.google.com#Website2#http://www.Link2.com#Website3#http://www.Link3.com"
  </div> 
  </div>
 </a>
```

Comment: Ooops thank you! I edited to a div, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Does this only have to work on desktop if so, you're fine but I don't know if it would work on mobile.

If you want some cleaner code and cut out the JS which I think is adding some complexity and requires some extra loading on the browser part, I would try a CSS only approach with :hover. You can achieve the same affect. An example is below. Also, I think linkedin uses this approach for there nav. I think bettycrocker.com and pillsbury.com uses this as well.

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!